# Can't remove curly braces from dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, word-count, curly-braces

I've written a function that takes in a phrase or sentence and outputs a dictionary with each entry being a word and the associated key being the character count.

When I call the function with `wordcount('hello my name is bobby')` it returns `{'hello': {5}, 'my': {2}, 'name': {4}, 'is': {2}, 'bobby': {5}}`
I'm not sure why the associated key has curly brackets?
I'd like it to return `{'hello':5, 'my':2, 'name':4, 'is':2, 'bobby':5}`. I've tried many things but can't get it to work.

```
def wordcount(text):
    
    from collections import defaultdict
    
    d = defaultdict(set)
    
    for word in text.split():
        d[word].add(len(word))
    return {a :b for a, b in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each value in your dictionary is a `set`, because you are using `defaultdict(set)` to define it. Then you add the words' lengths to the corresponding sets. That's why you get the braces when you print them.

Try:

```
d = {}
...
d[word] = len(word)
```

Comment: I wanted to piggyback off your answer, since your's covered it. OP is incorrectly referring to the value as the key. Thought they might like to know the correct terminology to avoid confusion. In a dictionary it is {key: value}. In their example, the key is the word, the value is the character count.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the default value of the defaultdict to "set" (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). That means: if there is no entry in the dict with that key, defaultdict adds a set. Afterwards, you add the length of the word to that set.

What you probably want does not require a default

```
def wordcount(text):
    d = {}

    for word in text.split():
        d[word] = len(word)
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

The values have curly brackets because they are `Set`s, which are lists of unique values.

Change these lines :

```py
d = defaultdict(set)
for word in text.split():
    d[word].add(len(word))
```

To :

```py
d = defaultdict()
for word in text.split():
    d[word] = len(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are declaring in advance that the value of any key that doesn't already exist in the dictionary will be of the type set, and you are adding the length of the word to a null set, which further supports your declaration.
Try the below code

```
def wordcount(text):
    from collections import defaultdict
    d = defaultdict(set) #I think you should change this to d={} or or to d=defaultdict{} or  to d=defaultdict(int), as you clearly want integer association only.

    for word in text.split():
        d[word]=len(word) #assigns an integer value to the key
    return {a :b for a, b in d.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. As you suggested, I used  d={} rather than the default dictionary.

Comment: Ignore this and look at my answer.

Comment: In future answers, please put your solution in the form of working code rather than just a comment.

Comment: @SargeATM It is a working code along with necessary comments. I just didn't choose to change the set initialisation of the dictionary values as it wasn't absolutely necessary. The important change that solves the problem is d[word]=len(word), which I have done.

Comment: @AMISHGUPTA I see, please excuse my comment. I'm new to reviewing posts and I didn't take the time to study the original question long enough.